# C# string processing and condition

Tags: c#, .net

I am reading and storing CMD commands in an array.

The last line in the array is the following string:

```
"[1] success"
```

I want to extract the 'success' part. So I stored the last element in a new variable and did some transformation:

```
var item = line[line.Count - 1];
item = item.Replace("[1]", "");
item = item.Replace("\"", "");
```

and then I do the following condition:

```
if (item == "success")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Successful processing");                    
} 
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("There was an error.");
}
```

When I do `MessageBox.Show(item);` the exact characters I need are printed - success.

Nonetheless, **the condition always returns the else output**. I don't understand why?

Comment: `if (line.Contains("success")) MessageBox.Show("Successful processing"); else MessageBox.Show("There was an error.");`?

Comment: " success" is not the same as "success" (note the extra space). It is a easy to make mistake with Strings.

Comment: `"[1] success".Replace("[1]", "").Replace("\"", "") != "success"`. Beware of things you cannot see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `IndexOf`:

```
if(line[line.Count - 1].IndexOf("success") > -1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Successful processing");    
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("There was an error.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check to see if `item` contains "success":

```
var item = line[line.Count - 1];

if (item.Contains("success"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Successful processing");    
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("There was an error.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
if(line[line.Count - 1].Contains("success"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Successful processing");                    
} 
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("There was an error.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a space at the start of your variable value. Try calling Trim() first and then compare.

```
var item = line[line.Count - 1];
item = item.Replace("[1]", "");
item = item.Replace("\"", ""); 
item = item.Trim();
```